# Gulp fix imports for generated files

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, gulp

I am generating typescript client (with openapi-generator) from an OpenApi description, but the generator has a known issue with polymorphism.

**Http Endpoint:**

```
public Shape get();
public IList<Circle> getCircles();
```

**Models:**

```
public Shape { ... }
public Circle : Shape { ... }
public Rectangle : Shape { ... }
```

**Generated Typescript client**

```
import { Circle | Rectangle } from '../model/models';
import { Circle } from '../model/models';

public get() : Observable<Circle | Rectangle>;
public getCircles() : Observavle<Circle[]>;
```

As you can see the problem is in the imports. One of my colleagues suggested to fix this with a custom gulp task with some Regex magic. Since I am totally unfamiliar with Regex, I dont know how to collect every import and replace them with one valid comma separated import line.

```
import { Circle, Rectangle } from '../model/models';
```

What I have already achieved is matching the import lines with this:

```
/import \{ (?<model>[A-Za-z0-9|, ]+) \} from \'\.\.\/model\/models\'\;/g
```

Found this npm package to replace regex matches [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace)

Comment: What type of pattern matching do you want to achieve?

Comment: Somehow I want to collect all the model classes from the file (import { Circle | Rectangle } from '../model/models'; lines), remove them, and insert a new line one with the valid comma separated syntax